# C++ STL class for Bitmap management

Tags: c++, memory, boost, stl, allocation

I have a requirement where i have to manage multiple chunks of equal sized memory buffers. I am planning to have a bitmap kind of data structure where each bit represents a memory buffer chunk. The value of the bit (0 or 1) will indicate if the memory chunk if free or used. This is a very simple scheme but it poses issues with scaling, as i have to do linear search in the bitmap data structure to find the next free bit.

Does C++ STL or boost provide classes for such logic with efficient implementation?

Regards
Naveen

Comment: [std::bitwise](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)?

Comment: If you want to O(0) search of next free bit, probably you need an extra data structure to store such information.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `std::bitset` for fixed size bitmap
or `vector<bool>` that optimized to bit vector for dynamic size